# How to check if a value exists in a list?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm relatively new to C# programming (programming as a whole, actually), but I've built an application to manage the application pools on a server that my team at work uses. It does everything it's supposed to fairly well, but the only issue I'm running into is in saving previously-used configurations to the app.config file so the user doesn't have to put them in manually every time. As it stands, I can save to and load from the file magnificently (along with all of the strings I need in each group).

The issue is that I want to do a cursory check to see if a Name string exists in the group before writing it. Example of the part of the app.config:

```
<appSettings>
 <add Name="RowName" MachineName="MS-02348" AppSrvName="AppServer" WebSrvName="AppNet"/>
 <add Name="RowName2" MachineName="MS-68186" AppSrvName="AppServer2" WebSrvName="AppNet2"/>
</appSettings>
```

So what I'm currently doing to load the values is I have a method that retrieves the appSettings/add nodes and throws them into a list, then sets the values to properties of an object. The reason I do this is so that I can have a drop-down that lists only the Name of an object, and then the rest of the information is all available for when I call the method on the selected item.

Anyway, what I'm running into now is that I want to make sure that if the Name already exists in the app.config, I prompt the user to write another name instead of saving it to the database. Having two child nodes with the same "Name" value would wreak havoc on my logic.

I tried a foreach to cycle through the objects in the list, but without knowing how many objects there could be I didn't know of an easy way of really saying it does or does not exist. I've also tried targeting the childnode based on the values listed in the node, but it seems to fail there too. I'm guessing that part is syntax, but it seems to match up with how the method list defines it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! Couple things: your example code is missing a closing quote on one of the `MachineName` attributes; and you should probably include your actual C# code that's processing the list, and detail what specific issues you have.

Comment: `but without knowing how many objects there could be I didn't know ...` - What do you mean by that? Why would that matter?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I didn't copy and paste, so must have missed that quote!

I didn't add any code because none of it does what I need...it's not so much that it won't compile or exceptions, but I can't think of a logical way to make it work. What I was doing is a foreach, and then comparing each result to see if the MachineName != null (MachineName is arbitrary...just making sure nothing comes back). The problem with that is that it'll come back false 3 times and true once. In my situation I want to make sure *all* come back false.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if (list.Any()) 
{ 
   // found something! 
}
else 
{
   // found nothing 
}
```

I always use `Any()` simply because it's the most performant.  `List.Count()` goes through each item and counts them, but you don't care about the number of items -- you only care if there's an item at all.  `Any()` will enumerate through the list and stop if it finds an item.  So, in the extreme case, in a list of a million items `Count()` will enumerate every single one and return while `Any()` will enumerate one and return.

Plus, it returns a bool, which is handy for more concise code. :)

As an added bonus, you can call `Any()` looking for specific things.  So, in a list of people I can look to see if there are any people older than 21 in it:

```
if (list.Any(person => person.Age > 21))
{
   // ...
}
```

*Edit:* Formatting.

Comment: That did it! The basic code I used is as follows:

ConnectionInfo.GetConnectionInfos() is my list creation methodology.

`if(ConnectionInfo.GetConnectionInfos().Any(info => info.Name == textBox4.Text))
{
//Complain that one exists
}`

textBox4 is one of the input boxes that get added to the list. This did the trick! Thanks everybody for the awesome suggestions!

Answer (score 6):

maybe something like this

```
        var list = new List<AppSettings>();
        var item = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == NameEnteredByUser);
        if (item == null)
        {
            //there is no such item
        }
        else
        {
           //notify the user
        }
```

or the Any extension method:

```
 var list = new List<AppSettings>();
        if (list.Any(x => x.Name == NameEnteredByUser))
        {
            //name exists
        }
        else
        {
            //no such name used before
        }
```

As a sidenote, have a unique field configured in your database so that when your programming logic fails you wont enter a record. corrupt data state in db is bad.

Comment: I think you need to use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First`.

Comment: not in this case because im checking vs null. firstordefault  returns an  object from the base constructor if no element is found not null. in this case getting a null shows that no item was found.

Comment: According to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb535050(v=vs.110).aspx) First will throw `InvalidOperationException` if there is no matching elements

Comment: @neo112 - I think kaptan is correct, when you do First(), my expectation would be that it would throw an excpetion if the result set was empty. Anyway, FirstOrDefault is safer still.

Comment: Yeah, you always want to use the XOrDefault versions unless you're explicitly handling the exception.  They'll return null if there's nothing there.  In your example it will throw right before the if statement.  That said, Any() is a much better approach.

Comment: yup, thanks for pointing that FirstOrDefault case out, i had something mixed up

Answer (score 2):

neo112 is correct in his logic, but I am unsure if the main problem you have is performance related, since you mention you dont know if it may get too long.

First, you could also do the following;

```
int count = list.Count(a => a.Name == NameEnteredByUser);
if(count > 0)
{
    // exists
}
```

I believe .Count() is faster than .First() (anecdotal evidence only) and personally think it's a bit cleaner.

Also, another thing you could try to do is to sort your list by name when adding to the appSettings node. Then, you should instantiate a SortedList instead of just List, then that would also (possitively) affect performance. But, I am unsure if sorting is an option for you.

Comment: Using list.Any would be quick than list.Count

Comment: list.Count() is a O(n), list.Any is worst case O(n) so you won't win in performance

Comment: @DarrenYoung good point, I always forget about .Any() . It's cleaner as well.

Comment: Theoretically, neo112 is right using standard O-notation.  Practically, though, if you had a call to `Count()` vs. `Any()` that included a lambda expression (e.g., my example below) on a large set, the difference could be pretty dramatic.  `Any()` seems better practice to me.